# Make pattern rule for subdirectories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

While testing the parallelization possibilities in case of recursive `make`, I have stumbled on a weird behavior with the pattern rules.

The `Makefile`:

```
## prepare the dir structure
# mkdir -p bs{1,2,3}
# for i in 1 2 3; do ln -s ../Makefile bs$i ; done

aaa:
        @echo $(CURDIR)
        sleep 1

s: bs1 bs2 bs3
        true

## alt1
bs1 bs2 bs3: ; +make -C $@ aaa

## alt2
#bs%: ; +make -C $@ aaa

.PHONY: s bs1 bs2 bs3
```

There are two alternatives how to specify the targets: either literally list all the targets in the recipe, *alt1* - `bs1 bs2 bs3` - or use the `%` pattern, *alt2* - `bs%`.

When I run `make -j s` with the *alt1*, it works as expected.

But if I switch to *alt2* (comment out alt1 rule, comment in alt2 rule), the `make -j s` runs only the `true`, and silently ignores the prerequisite `bs1`, `bs2` and `bs3` targets.

Likewise, with *alt1*, `make bs1` calls the sub-make, while with *alt2*, `make bs1` says that `Nothing to be done for 'bs1'.` The trick with the `.force` dummy target didn't change the behavior.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets)

> The implicit rule search (see [Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules)) is skipped for `.PHONY` targets.

`bs%:` is an implicit rule, so it is ignored.

Comment: So in other words, in this case, the target name may not coincide with the directory name?

Comment: @Dummy00001 It can as you've seen with the first rule you defined, you just can't use pattern rules together with `.PHONY` targets.